# How to set User in MVC 6 Controller test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have Unit tests for MVC6 controllers where the controller has the [AllowAnonymous] attribute. However a number of my controllers do not have this attribute and I am unable to test those controllers. Also some controllers which allow anonymous access return different data sets depending upon whether the user is authenticated or anonymous.

I have not been able to determine how to set the User details for use in a test and am beginning to think it may not be possible. I hope this is not the case.

Comment: Don't bother testing controllers. Test directly the application services that are used by the controller.

Comment: @MikeSW testing the controllers does verify that security and routing are configured correctly and have not been changed from build to build. It would be possible to extract most content of the controller action to a service where the Controller context, user details and other dependencies are supplied to the service to make this more testable, but it would be simpler to have a mechanism to set the User.

Comment: And you'll have tests but the code will still be coupled. You know that having trouble doing test after is a hint that your codebase is not very maintainable.

Comment: @MikeSW and that problem may originate in the framework. But I am separating out the rest into services.

Answer (score 0):

Jerrie Pelser posted this exact issue in his blog in Oct. However since then the framework has changed and it 'almost' works.  I did find a solution to the problem and posted it in the comment on his blog.

http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/unit-testing-controllers-aspnet5

Basically read the blog and my comments at the end, then create your controller like this.

```
var controller = new MyController()
{
     ActionContext = new ActionContext
     {
          HttpContext = httpContext
     },
     Url = new UrlHelper(),
     TempData = Mock.Of<ITempDataDictionary>()
};
```